# Drawing color content of NSColorWell to an NSTextView

Tags: cocoa

Thanks again for the help -

What's the best way to insert a 60x60 pixel square representation of a color displayed in a colorWell into a textView? I know how to reference the values of the displayed color.

Again. thanks.

-paul.

This action works using the colorWell as the sender. It doesn't work when I add it to a button initialized action:

```
    NSColor *wellColor;

wellColor = [colorWell color];

   float
   red, green, blue;


   red = [wellColor redComponent];
   green = [wellColor greenComponent];
   blue = [wellColor blueComponent];

[colorWell setColor:wellColor];


[colorWell setColor:[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:red green:green blue:blue   alpha:1.0]];

wellColor = [colorWell color];
NSRect r = NSMakeRect(190, 130, 100, 100);
NSBezierPath *bp = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:r];
NSColor *color = wellColor;
[color set];
[bp fill];
```

Comment: In what method does this code exist? Where does the text view come into things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use NSTextAttachment and attach it as an image (drawing a solid-color-filled image is a simple task you can learn about with the basic drawing documentation). Otherwise, you'll have to get into subclassing and customizing parts of the text system to make room for and draw the color there yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I looked through the drawing documentation. The following works in the applicationDidFinishLaunching method at startup. However when I use this code in an action - nothing happens. Can someone explain? Thanks allot. 
     NSColor  *wellColor;
     wellColor = [colorWell color];
     
     
     NSRect r = NSMakeRect(190, 130, 100, 100);
     NSBezierPath *bp = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:r];
     NSColor *color = wellColor;
     [color set];
     [bp fill];

Comment: This is not enough information to determine what's going wrong. You're going to have to post all your relevant code. Place it into your original question (hit the edit link), not comments or answers.